# Rails random records generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ask myself if there is a gem or a method to generate a large amount of records with random data (which are valid for the model)

The goal is to test my application with a lot of data in the database.

I didn't find anything on the web, but i don't have use right keywords.

Do you know something like that?

Comment: you need `gem 'ffaker'`

Comment: `Faker,` plus maybe something like `machinist `or `factory girl ` to help with the automation of generating lots of data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Faker](https://rubygems.org/gems/faker) gem. And, following is sample code to create 10 user records. You can create as many records as you want.

```
10.times do  
  user = User.new
  user.first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
  user.last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
  user.email = Faker::Internet.email
  user.phone = Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone
  user.save
end
```

Comment: This corresponds to my need. However, I use the 2 gems `faker` and `ffaker` because each have specific generators.

Answer (score 3):

I find the [`faker`](https://rubygems.org/gems/faker) gem quite useful. You'll have to write your record creation code yourself, though.

Answer (score 2):

Few more gems for fake data

> Fabrication - A simple and powerful object generation library.

> factory_bot - A library for setting up Ruby objects as test data.
>
> Fake Person - Uses some of the most popular given & surnames in the US
> & UK.
>
> faker - A library for generating fake data such as names, addresses,
> and phone numbers.
>
> ffaker - A faster Faker, generates dummy data, rewrite of faker.
>
> Forgery - Easy and customizable generation of forged data

> Machinist - Fixtures aren't fun. Machinist is